# NextJS13 doesn't scroll to top after redirect

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, next-link

I've wrote a whole code of site using  but unfortunetly in NextJS 13 it doesn't scroll me to top of the page after redirect. Any ideas why? I checked documentation and there is scroll={true} as default, even if I added it doesnt work :/

I don't add some code becouse it's global but here's example of my Link:

```
<Link href={`/dzial/${department.urlName}`} className={`${ className } w-48 h-48 xl:w-48 xl:h-48 2xl:w-64 2xl:h-64 items-center justify-start relative cursor-pointer hover:scale-[1.1] duration-300`}>
```

There is no error message. Just after redirect, page doesnt scroll to top.

Comment: Did you try `useRouter` hook? Because the `scroll` property is a feature specific to the `router.push` method. Check out this section: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router#routerpush

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: are you using nextjs routing system? its hard to find an issue when so many variables are unknown in your post.